# Punctuating a sentence with "because" followed by multiple clauses

Tags: punctuation

This question or a similar one may have been answered here before. But I couldn't find an answer. So I'm going to ask how the grammarians here would punctuate the following sentence:

"The author argued that his results differed from previous results because the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researches used and his sample came from a different part of the world than the samples that those researchers used."

The following are several of the ways I tried to punctuate it:

(1) "The author argued that his results differed from previous results because the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researches used, and his sample came from a different part of the world than the samples that those researchers used."

(2) "The author argued that his results differed from previous results, because the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researches used and his sample came from a different part of the world than the samples that those researchers used."

(3) "The author argued that his results differed from previous results, because the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researches used, and his sample came from a different part of the world than the samples that those researchers used."

(4) "The author argued that his results differed from previous results because the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researches used and because his sample came from a different part of the world than the samples that those researchers used."

(5) "The author argued that his results differed from previous results because (a) the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researches used and (b) his sample came from a different part of the world than the samples that those researchers used."

I suppose I could rewrite the sentence, but I'd still appreciate an answer because I frequently have problems with sentences like this.

Thanx

Comment: The author argued his results differed from previous ones due to  previous researchers' methods and the provenance of their samples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a grammarian, but I would write the sentence as:

> The author argued that his results differed from previous results both because the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researchers used, and because his sample came from a different part of the world than the samples that those researchers used.

That is, I would add the word “both” before the the reasons, and repeat the word “because”.

I might also say “... part of the world than the samples that those researchers had used” (adding the word “had”), but YYMV.

Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I would punctuate it - though punctuation can be a very personal thing. And who is to say who's right?

However I would first propose two grammatical improvements one could make.

i) I would place a "had" in between "researche(r)s" and "used". (The pluperfect would be my choice of tense here).

ii) And I would change "than" to "to". I know Americans say "different than",(and there are 290 million of them to 64 million of us) but I stand by "different to" - different is not a comparative.

***The author argued that his results differed from previous results, because the methods he used differed from the methods that previous researchers had used. And his sample came from a different part of the world to the samples that those researchers had used.***

As you will note I am a fan of short sentences. I loathe long ones that have multiple clauses, which you have to re-read in order to comprehend.

Comment: Thanks very much for the opinion. I also considered breaking it up into two sentences, as you did, but I felt that a single sentence flowed better. I also considered using the pluperfect, but the editors of science journals prefer to save space by using the simple past, and your suggestion that I use "to," rather than "than,"  sounds strange to me. Nevertheless, I appreciate your suggestions. Take care :-)